# Difference between superclass and supertype and the difference between subclass and subtype

Tags: oop, class, polymorphism

Are they interchangeable terms? Would you be able to give formal definitions and also examples?

Comment: They are interchangeable in the same way your father and your son are.

Answer (score 3):

Both terms (superclass and supertype) are related, but they are not exactly interchangeable.

Only **classes** have **superclasses**, while other **classifiers** have **supertypes**. Since Class is also a Classifier, a superclass is always a supertype (because superclass redefines the general association between classifiers), but the opposite is not true.

For instance, the primitive type `long` in Java [is defined](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10) as a *supertype* of `int`. Since primitive types are not classes, `long` is not a superclass of `int`.

Another example: in UML, components and interfaces are different from classes (all of them are classifiers), then it is not correct to say "the superclass of a component" but "the supertype of a component".

Answer (score 0):

To say that A is a subclass of B merely asserts that A is formed using inheritance.
To say that a is a subtype of B asserts that A preserves the meaning of all the operations in B.

It is possible to form subclasses that are not subtypes; and (in some languages at least) form subtypes that are not subclasses.

Comment: subclasses that are not subtypes sounds a bit sketchy since subtypes are eventually defined through subclasses